# MyFirebaseMessagingService is not working but notification is shown

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, onclick, firebase-cloud-messaging

I receive notifications from Firebase but my classes I've created not working (not involved in the actions). Seems like they are shown by default.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notifiBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of FCM messages: notification and data.  They are handled differently in the receiving device.  If you are sending a notification message with no data fields, the notification is generated by the client SDK and `onMessageReceived()` is not invoked.  This is [explained in more detail in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?authuser=0#notifications_and_data_messages):

> - **Notification Message**: FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages
>     have a predefined set of user-visible keys and an optional data
>     payload of custom key-value pairs.
> - **Data Message**: Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.