# Why "MyFirebaseMessagingService" class is not been executing when notification is being pushed from the server

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made a class in my android app package named as `MyFirebaseMessagingService` that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` of Google. I have done all the prescribed steps that were mentioned in google docs but my class is not been executed when a push notification is sent by the server(Laravel)..

I received  the notification in my android notification tray but as this class is not been executed I'm not able to do anything with that notification:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Toast.makeText(this,remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // here i want that whenever this class executes and this
        // onMessageReceived method is being called this toast
        // should be toasted .

    }
```

when I apply the breakpoints on the Toast line it doesn't executes when notification is sent ..

Comment: read this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287828/myfirebasemessagingservice-is-not-working-but-notification-is-shown

Comment: this too, https://gist.github.com/jirawatee/85d4b46a89b9ae821b63c31f5d5189de

Comment: thank you @notTdar find the solution..

Comment: @notTdar can you please tell me how to open any other activity instead of launcher activity when notification is being opened?

Comment: read about pending intenet, everything you want to know is there, opening activity, service..

Comment: i had read and implement but the class didn't executes hence the code inside that class(MyFirebaseMessaging) did not executes as well.